# Conditionally format a range based on the value of a single cell outside of it

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am using conditional formatting with a custom formula. I want to highlight rows in the range `A2:B11` if the values in `$B2` (column `B` starting at row `2`) is greater than the value in the cell `D5`.

I can get it to work if I "hardcode" the value (which I presently happen to know to be `326`), by using the formula `=$B2>326`; but if the value changes, I don't want to have to update the formula. How can I refer to the value in cell `D5`? I tried `=$B2>D5`, but that doesn't work (and I don't know why).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the conditional formula `=$B2>$D$5`.